# Using three Strings to get a list of data from an oracledb in sprinboot application

Tags: spring, oracle, jpql

Please Good afternoon. Please I converted the below query

```
(select * from dispute_request_data d where d.arbiter = 'UNKNOWN' and to_date(to_char(tran_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') between '01-Apr-2019' and '30-Apr-2019';)
```

which runs perfectly on sql editor and returns a list of data to this

```
(@Query(value= "select * from dispute_request_data d where d.arbiter = :processor and to_date(to_char(tran_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') between to_date(:dateFrom,'DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date(:dateTo,'DD-MON-YYYY')",nativeQuery = true)
    List<DisputeRequest> findDisputeRequestByProcessorAndDateRange(@Param("processor") String processor,@Param("dateFrom") String dateFrom,@Param("dateTo") String dateTo);)
```

but it returns an empty list. Please help me... The tran_date column on the dispute request table is a timestamp thats why i am trying to convert it to_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something is date or timestamp you should use this type. Do not convert back and again. Now your query depends on national date settings and may fail on different environments. In queries use date literals:

```
  where d.arbiter = 'UNKNOWN' 
    and date '2019-04-01' <= tran_date and tran_date < date '2019-05-01'
```

In your application send parameters `:dateFrom` and `:dateTo` as dates, not strings and change condition to:

```
  where d.arbiter = :processor 
    and :dateFrom <= tran_date and tran_date < :dateTo + 1
```

---

> Is there no way I can use the formatted string to get the data?

```
  where d.arbiter = :processor     
    and to_date(:dateFrom, 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'nls_date_language=english') <= tran_date 
    and tran_date < to_date(:dateTo, 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'nls_date_language=english') + 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Ponder Stibbons.. but the parameter i am getting is in string...which i converted to a date then reformatted it to DD-MMM-YYYY so as to accomodate the working query in oracle sql. Is there no way I can use the formatted string to get the data?

Comment: Sorry @Ponder Stibbons if this is a stupid question but why are using + 1?

Comment: Note that I used ` < ` for dateTo. Dates in your table may contain hours and minutes part, this way we will not loose values like `30-April-2019 15:47:32`. This solution also allows effective usage of index on `tran_date`, it's better than `trunc(tran_date)`.

Comment: Thank you but its returning ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Here you can see working demo: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2fcab8d7d09012aba6a1471bc424cc7).

Comment: String dateTo  = "30-Apr-2019"   and String dateFrom  = "01-Apr-2019"

Comment: I have no access to your data, NLS settings. You can see in demo working example. Please remove date conditions and see if it is working, then hardcode dates. Or remove nls_date_language part, it is not needed for you. Check if you are using `Mon` and `MON`. Just debug :) You will find solution.